# Presto how to directly replace an item in array

Tags: sql, database, presto

I have a database that one of the columns is an array containing many information, see below:
**{"2":"KJH78","4":"CL","10":"Sell"}** 
The index 2 stands for the ID.

Now I would like to hash the ID, and directly replace the ID value in the array, using Presto SELECT statement.
I have not found any useful Presto commands that do the job.

### What I have

| acc_id | acc_id_hash | flds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KJH78 | 2bjkse879sdf2kk7 | {"2":"KJH78", ......} |

### What I want

| acc_id | acc_id_hash | flds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KJH78 | 2bjkse879sdf2kk7 | {"2":"2bjkse879sdf2kk7 ", ......} |

### Failed attempts

Ignore the result of hash function as the value was manually changed to protect data

**1. Using replace function**

```
SELECT element_at(flds, 2) AS acc_id,
       xxhash64(to_utf8(element_at(flds, 2))) as acc_id_hash,
       replace(flds[2], cast(from_utf8(xxhash64(to_utf8(element_at(flds, 2)))) as varchar)),
       flds
FROM mscs_feed
WHERE date_string = '2021-05-26'
and element_at(flds, 2) is not null
limit 10
```

Result:

| acc_id | acc_id_hash | _col2 | flds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KJH78 | 2bjkse879sdf2kk7 | KJH78 | {"2":"KJH78", ......} |

Problem: The flds[2] is varchar, hash is varbinary. The replace function needs both parameters to be the same type. After converting the types, the hash becomes meaningless.

**2. Trim the array, then add the hash into it**

```
SELECT element_at(flds, 2) AS acc_id,
       xxhash64(to_utf8(element_at(flds, 2))) as acc_id_hash,
       slice(flds, 1, cardinality(flds) - 1),
       flds
FROM mscs_feed
WHERE date_string = '2021-05-26'
and element_at(flds, 2) is not null
limit 10
```

Problem: Error line 3: Unexpected parameters (map(integer,varchar), integer, bigint) for function slice. Expected: slice(array(E), bigint, bigint) E

Please let me know if the question is unclear, or more information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sure. Should I edit my question or directly answer here in comment?

Comment: Should have been in the question originally, so if you can, put it there.

Comment: The question was updated.